# How to lock Xbox home so child cannot add to it

Tags: xbox-one

I've already set the accounts to limit what I'm after but I can still add items onto Home that I want to block.  Is there a way to lock home to a shared profile or disallow other accounts to add items to home without your approval?

Comment: By "shared profile" do you mean you have 1 profile used by multiple people? If so, I'd recommend you make a child account for your child instead. Then it won't even matter what your child puts on the home screen, since it'll be for his/her profile only. Sharing accounts is a huge headache waiting to happen. By the time your child becomes an adult and leaves, you'll have to worry about how to split the account, which is simply not possible.

Comment: I'm trying to limit which apps they can add to their home screen. Specifically, I'm trying to block 'Community'.